# ADF ActionListener for operation

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a button made from a data controls 'CreateInsert' operation. 
I have set a boolean in my code (initialized to false) and when the createInsert button is clicked, I want to check this boolean before executing it's operation. 
However, in this button's ActionListener, is nothing related to the CreateInsert operation I need to stop if my boolean check returns true..

Now my question is, where is the real Action handling for the CreateInsert button/how can I control it (stop it from executing) in my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i have no idea what you are trying to ask. Please take a moment and carefully reword your question ( grammar counts!) and I'll see if I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a managed bean to the create insert button(I hope u can do that).
now open the managed bean java class , it automatically contains create insert method somewhat like this :::

BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
    OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("CreateInsert1");
    Object result = operationBinding.execute();
    if (!operationBinding.getErrors().isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return null;